# Python openpyxl dataframe data writing in excel and clearing the sheet content

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

The following is the code that supports appending the data in xlsx sheet.

```
import pandas as pd from openpyxl import load_workbook from openpyxl.utils.dataframe
import dataframe_to_rows

wb = load_workbook('./test.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1'] 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [11, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]}) 
for r in dataframe_to_rows(df):
        ws.append(r) 
wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

1. This is appending data everytime I run the code, also the data is placed from Row number 2; Why the excel data not starting from (0,0) cell.My requirement is to update the data from (0,0)
2. Since append is used it is appending the data every time when the function is called.My requirement is to clean this sheet(erase the content of this sheet1 alone) and add the data frame data starting from 0,0 cells.W hat shall be the code to achieve 1 and 2 requirements.
   (I do not want to overwrite sheet2 and other sheet content during this operation)

Any help is highly appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `dataframe_to_rows` call is adding an extra empty row and thats why you are seeing an extra row

```
>>> df
   Data
0    11
1    20
2    30
3    20
4    15
5    30
6    45
>>> 
>>> print( [*dataframe_to_rows(df)] )
[[None, 'Data'], FrozenList([None]), [0, 11], [1, 20], [2, 30], [3, 20], [4, 15], [5, 30], [6, 45]]
>>>
```

Are you sure you want to use openpyxl. If not you can do it easily as follows

```
>>> fname = './test.xlsx'
>>> sheet = 'Sheet2'
>>> with ExcelWriter(fname, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
...     writer.book = load_workbook(fname)
...     if sheet in writer.book:
...         del writer.book[sheet]
...     df.to_excel(writer, sheet)
```

Comment: If this is not going to delete the content of the sheet2 ,sheet3 etc ,the method would be ok ; let me first check this and feedback

Comment: This and ExcelWriter and xlsxwriter both is not satisfying the condition that it should not delete other existing sheets in the excel file. This is the reason i selected openpyxl.Any better solution ?

Comment: @MarxBabu I have updated the answer to retain the existing sheets.. Can you give another try

Comment: The above-changed code keeps the existing sheets no doubt, The issue is everytime you run the code it creates new sheet as sheet11,sheet13 and there it places the data.I always want to place the data in sheet1 alone. Rest of the worksheet not to be disturbed. How i shall contact ? any e m a il

Comment: The above code would always create the specified sheet named `Sheet2` and I have tested it. I dont think it would create sheet11 or sheet13

Comment: really it creates new sheets, if you keep the last line code as 'Sheet1' then sheet11 sheet12 etc coming, if this is 'sheet2' sheet 21 sheet22 added everytime you would run the file . Run ones the code open the excel and check,close the excel and then run the same code now you would c this issue. No still the issue is there.

Comment: @MarxBabu I updated the answer again, to delete the sheets if they exist, before creating one. Can you check if it helps

Comment: Thank you! This solves the issue. I have few more database related queries that I post later for support.

Comment: This works fine as I mentioned earlier, One query this reformats other sheet content why? Example I had some charts in the other sheet now the formatting is completely removed from it. Any suggestion to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the excel data not starting from (0,0) cell.

Because [the `.append` method](http://nullege.com/codes/search/openpyxl.worksheet.Worksheet.append) of the worksheet class:

> Appends a group of values at the bottom of the current sheet.

In other words, this method finds the next available/empty row, and dumps the data *there*, which makes sense. How else would you expect an `append` method to work? `list.append` doesn't write to item 0, it *adds a new member to the list*. Same idea with the `worksheet.append` method.

In order to clear the existing cells first, try:

[How to clear a range of values in an Excel workbook using OpenPyXl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36582460/how-to-clear-a-range-of-values-in-an-excel-workbook-using-openpyxl)

Comment: It is fine append does the job; How to avoid this and write starting from 0,0 cells or from the cells from which it has to be written?

Comment: @MarxBabu append *only works* if you clear the sheet first, which is a question that's already been answered on SO, as linked in my answer.