# Using openpyxl to convert Excel spreadsheets to CSVs, how can I turn zeros into blanks?

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl

I've got a simple code for reading a specific spreadsheet from a workbook and writing its values to a csv.  The spreadsheet is very formula-heavy as it's taking data from a raw_data sheet and crunching it.  However, there are some cells where no information was added, and therefore the cell is blank.  But since there's a formula there, openpyxl is turning it to a zero.  How can I convert those zeros to an empty space between 2 commas?

```
import openpyxl
import csv

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:\\Users\\Staff\\Desktop\\Test\\MS098_AlexLibRecords.xlsx', data_only = True)
sh = wb["MODS"]
with open('C:\\Users\\Staff\\Desktop\\Test\\MODS_OR.csv', 'wb') as f:
    c = csv.writer(f)
    for r in sh.rows:
        c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this for a solution?

```
for r in sh.rows:
    out_val_list = list()
    for cell in r:
        out_val = cell.value
        if out_val == 0 or str(out_val).strip() == "0":
            out_val = None
        out_val_list.append(out_val)
    c.writerow(out_val_list)
```

Comment: Nope.  It did some weird stuff.  Multiplied each row by 10 or so, doubling up the information (10+ rows of the header, 10+ copies of the 2nd row, etc).  Zeros were still there, oddly.  I copied your code to exist after the '''for r in sh.rows.''' line.

Comment: Added an edited solution, please do try it out and let me know. We have considered the 0 to be either a string or an int and corrected the row cases

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong.  Your code should replace my "c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])" line, right?  If so, that last run gave me an Attribute Error of "'long' object has no attribute 'strip'"  And it also only printed the header to my cvs.

Comment: So your item is in a long format which means numbers are represented in long.. so the string strip might not be necessary, so this should work out now. Try this one edited again and I'm sure it will work.

Comment: The correct way is to set the cell to `None`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36583462/7919597

Comment: Joe, where would I put that?

Comment: High-Octane, that worked.  However, for some reason some strings within my spreadsheet are being put into the csv with quotes around them.  Not sure why.  It's random cells.  One won't have quotes, and the one next to it will.

Comment: Do they contain any commas in them or anything that might need to be escaped?

Comment: Yes.  That's why.  Thanks!